# nodes Similarity in R

Tags: r, graph, dataframe, nodes, similarity

i try to compute similarity between a pre-known node and all the other nodes of the graph in R. and at each step, if the similarity exceeds a certain threshold i put the node in a vector, for storing all the nodes in dataframe ( for each node, i will give their similars).

but,this code give only the last node, and his last similar node.

```
v <- DC2$node[order(-DC2$'Centrality')]
Nei1 <- neighbors(g1,as.character(v[1]),1)
vec <- numeric()
if(length(Nei1) > 0) {
    for (i in 1:length(V(g1))) {
        Nei2 <- neighbors(g,as.character(V(g1)[i]),1)
        k1 <- as.numeric(degree(g1,as.character(v[1])))
        k2 <- as.numeric(degree(g1,as.character(V(g1)[i])))
        Simhpi <- (length(intersect(Nei1,Nei2)) / min(k1,k2))
        if (Simhpi >= 0.5) {
            for (j in 1:length(V(g1))) {
                vv <- V(g1)[j]
                vec[j] <- c(vec,vv$name)
            }
        }
   }
}
nn<- data.frame(node=as.character(v[1]), Nei=vec)
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Your question lacks certain essential details: What data structure do you use to represent your graph (igraph it seems)? What similarity measure do you mean to use to compare the nodes?

Comment: @VincentLabatut. yes,i use igraph. i mean the "Hub Promoted Index" similarity. but my problem isn't similarity, it's in this part, when i try to compute and store the similar nodes in the vector **vec**,it's give me only the last value( i.e the last compared node):                                               `for (j in 1:length(V(g1))) {
                vv <- V(g1)[j]
                vec[j] <- c(vec,vv$name)
            }`

Comment: Well, if we want to execute you source code, we need to know which library contains the `degree` function. Also, we need the `DC2` data, or preferably a simpler substitute.